# gRPC: What is the correct way to shut down a synchronous server in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc, rpc

I have a gprc server that has a synchronous service.I have read the grpc document below.(https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/)
And I am confused about how to shutdown a synchronous grpc server? I have find a way in the documentation of asynchronous(https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/async/)
The following is my code, but is that right?

```
ServerBuilder builder;
builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
builder.RegisterService(&service);
std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
server->Wait();
```

in other thread, I call

```
server->Shutdown();
```

Am i right???

Comment: There is a similar question,but it's topic is asynchronous server.

Comment: Why would you call `.BuildAndStart()` twice? Plus you call `Shutdown()` on a newly created instance immediately afterwards. That doesn't make sense. Especially since `Wait()` exits only when the server is shutting down anyway. You shutdown a server by either killing a process or calling `Shutdown()` from some other thread. In particular if you don't give an option to shutdown the server internally (via grpc call or something) then there's nothing you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I should not call  .BuildAndStart() twice , it is my fault when writing the question. I call the .BuildAndStart() only once in my real code. And I really call Shutdown() in another thread. I just want to know if this approach is right?

Comment: I think it is. According to these docs: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_interface.html#ac36477b6a7593a4e4608c7eb712b0d70 the call to `Wait()` will return if some other thread calls `Shutdown()`. I think this implies that `Shutdown()` is thread safe and it should be fine.